Terminate playwright test on test fail
I have a codebuild project where I have some playwright tests running. I want the build to fail whenever a test fails, but when the test fails it just hangs and the log tells us to terminate with Ctrl + C.
Any idea on how to trigger a build fail when a test fails in playwright?
What I've tried:

In the build commands,

       - npm ci
       - npx playwright install 
       - npx playwright install-deps  
       - npx playwright test
       - |
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
          echo "Playwright tests failed. Failing the build."
          exit 1  # Exit with a non-zero code to indicate failure
        fi


In the test:

      try {
        // Your test logic here
        expect(thing).toBe(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Test failed:', error);
        process.exit(1);
        throw error; // Throws the error, causing the test to fail
      }

I get this error: Error: worker process exited unexpectedly (code=1, signal=null) but the test just keeps on running.

Use Assertions
Let the test run simply without having any try-catch blocks however cover at least one assertion so that if the test fails ,it will return a non-zero exit code.
AWS CodeBuild will recognize this non-zero exit code and fail the build automatically.
Simple Example:
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('example test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  const title = await page.title();
  expect(title).toBe('Example Domain');// if this fails , it will return a non zero exit code.
});

